# How to develop a distributed system with Apache CXF D-OSGi?

Tags: cxf, dosgi

My development environment and requirement: Eclipse3.6, Equinox framework, Apache cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.2.jar

I want to try a demo distributed program, but it seems that the imported cxf jar could't work normally. First of all, the cxf-dosgi I downloaded is a zip file, I simply renamed its extension to jar. And I imported it into Eclipse workbench with no error prompted.
But when I try to run it with osgi, osgi.service, javax.servlet,  it shows massive console messages in red color which makes me panic.

Actually when I add the service, impl, client bundles, the system can't work, I think something must be wrong when starting the cxf-dosgi bundle.

Who can help me?

```
osgi> Setting HttpService port to: 8080
felix.fileinstall.poll  (ms)   2000
felix.fileinstall.dir            D:\Program Files\Eclipse3.6\.\load
felix.fileinstall.debug          -1
felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start          true
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.mortbay.jetty).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.Activator start
信息: TopologyManager: start()
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.discovery.zookeeper.Activator updated
信息: Received configuration update for Zookeeper Discovery: null
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl getRegistrationProperties
信息: EndpointListener: current filter: []
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager$1 addingService
信息: TopologyManager: new EndpointListener that wants to be informed about wants going on ... 
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.log.LogService)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.apache.felix.cm.PersistenceManager)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.remoteserviceadmin.EndpointListener)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.remoteserviceadmin.EndpointListener)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: null
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.remoteserviceadmin.RemoteServiceAdmin)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping import request for excluded classs [org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping import request for excluded classs [org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping import request for excluded classs [org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=java.net.ContentHandler)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping import request for excluded classs [java.net.ContentHandler]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl extendScope
信息: EndpointListener: extending scope by (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl updateRegistration
信息: EndpointListenerImpl: filters: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl getRegistrationProperties
信息: EndpointListener: current filter: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager$1 modifiedService
信息: TopologyManager: EndpointListener changed ... 
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl extendScope
信息: EndpointListener: extending scope by (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl updateRegistration
信息: EndpointListenerImpl: filters: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl getRegistrationProperties
信息: EndpointListener: current filter: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager$1 modifiedService
信息: TopologyManager: EndpointListener changed ... 
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl extendScope
信息: EndpointListener: extending scope by (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl updateRegistration
信息: EndpointListenerImpl: filters: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl getRegistrationProperties
信息: EndpointListener: current filter: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager$1 modifiedService
信息: TopologyManager: EndpointListener changed ... 
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl extendScope
信息: EndpointListener: extending scope by (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl updateRegistration
信息: EndpointListenerImpl: filters: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl getRegistrationProperties
信息: EndpointListener: current filter: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager$1 modifiedService
信息: TopologyManager: EndpointListener changed ... 
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.runnable.StartupMonitor)
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl extendScope
信息: EndpointListener: extending scope by (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.runnable.StartupMonitor)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl updateRegistration
信息: EndpointListenerImpl: filters: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.runnable.StartupMonitor)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl getRegistrationProperties
信息: EndpointListener: current filter: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.runnable.StartupMonitor)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:19:48 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager$1 modifiedService
信息: TopologyManager: EndpointListener changed ... 
2011-5-10 20:19:49 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: *** Filter: (objectClass=org.springframework.osgi.context.event.OsgiBundleApplicationContextListener)
2011-5-10 20:19:49 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl added
信息: ListenerHookImpl: skipping request from myself
Loading Intent map from [classpath:/OSGI-INF/cxf/intents/intent-map.xml]
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.dsw.qos.IntentMap setIntents
信息: Injected intents: {addressing=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.WSPolicyFeature@cbf9bd, logging=org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature@17918f0, SOAP=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingConfiguration@1546dbc, SOAP.1_1=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingConfiguration@1546dbc, SOAP.1_2=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingConfiguration@1f08ed8, HTTP=PROVIDED}
application context: org.springframework.osgi.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext@384065: display name [OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution, config=classpath:/OSGI-INF/cxf/intents/intent-map.xml)]; startup date [Tue May 10 20:19:58 CST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
retrieved intent map: IntentMap: {addressing=org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.WSPolicyFeature@cbf9bd, logging=org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature@17918f0, SOAP=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingConfiguration@1546dbc, SOAP.1_1=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingConfiguration@1546dbc, SOAP.1_2=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingConfiguration@1f08ed8, HTTP=PROVIDED}
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.RemoteServiceAdminList$1 addingService
信息: Adding RemoteServiceAdmin to list of admins 
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.RemoteServiceAdminList$1 addingService
信息: enlisted RemoteEventAdmins: 0
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager triggerExportImportForRemoteSericeAdmin
信息: TopologyManager: triggerExportImportForRemoteSericeAdmin()
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl removed
信息: ListenerHookImpl: removed: [org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked@10849bc(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.runnable.StartupMonitor)]
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.ListenerHookImpl removed
信息: (objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.runnable.StartupMonitor)
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl reduceScope
信息: EndpointListener: reducing scope by (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.runnable.StartupMonitor)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl updateRegistration
信息: EndpointListenerImpl: filters: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.EndpointListenerImpl getRegistrationProperties
信息: EndpointListener: current filter: [(&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.ConsoleSession)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.service.debug.DebugOptionsListener)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331))), (&(objectClass=org.eclipse.osgi.signedcontent.SignedContentFactory)(!(endpoint.framework.uuid=69a8c12f-1cad-4479-977b-591dc124d331)))]
2011-5-10 20:20:05 org.apache.cxf.dosgi.topologymanager.TopologyManager$1 modifiedService
信息: TopologyManager: EndpointListener changed ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The CXF dOSGi single bundle distribution is packaged as a jar so there must have been a problem downloading it, although from your log it does appear to be being deployed.

Try this [link for cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.2.jar](http://www.apache.org/dist/cxf/dosgi/1.2/cxf-dosgi-ri-singlebundle-distribution-1.2.jar)

As an alternative to CXF try ECF ([Eclipse Communication Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/)).